No pipe found with name ''
I'm trying to use a pipe i created in Angular, but i'm getting the error  No pipe found with name 'RefPipe'.
I searched for info about this error and they told me to import it. But i tried to import it in different folders and it's not working.
I imported the pipe on app.module.ts first, so it could be accesed globally but it isn't working.
Then i tried to import it on the ts file of the component where i'm trying to use the pipe but i keep getting error. Any help would be appreciated.
<p>Id libro:{{libroPadre.id_book | RefPipe}}</p>

import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Book } from '../module/book';
import { NgClass, UpperCasePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-card',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    NgClass,
    UpperCasePipe,
    CommonModule

  ],
  templateUrl: './card.component.html',
  styleUrl: './card.component.css'
})

import { RefPipe } from './pipes/ref.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    FormRegisterComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
    RefPipe,
    CommonModule
    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    AddBookComponent,
    UpdateBookComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
    provideClientHydration(),
    BooksService,
    RefPipe 
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


The pipe is:
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
   name: 'ref',
   standalone: true
})
export class RefPipe implements PipeTransform {
   transform(value: string, count:number):string {
     let result = "";
     
     for(let i = 0; i<count;i++){
         result += "-ref" +  value
     }
 
     return result;                          
   }
}



Please share the code of RefPipe. You are probably using the class name instead of the pipe selector

And you are mixing things up: you are providing the pipe in AppModule, while you are using it in CardComponent without importing it in the AppModule

This is the pipe code. And i imported the pipe in the file called app.module.ts and in the file called app.module.server.ts. inline `import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
name: 'ref',
standalone: true
})
export class RefPipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(value: string, count:number):string {
let result = "";
for(let i = 0; i<count;i++){
result += "-ref" +  value
}
return result;

}
}
`,

Please, edit the question so that it's readable

From the code of your pipe it seems that you should use ref in the template (i.e. the pipe's name) and not the class name RefPipe.
Furthermore, you are working with standalone components and pipes, so you don't need any modules, you just have to add your RefPipe into the imports array of your module.
So you would have:
ts
@Component({
  imports: [
    ... your imports,
    RefPipe
  ],
  standalone: true,
  ...
})

template
<p>Id libro:{{libroPadre.id_book | ref}}</p>

